# Allowing global #tags in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-organization, trello-labels

I don't use the Labels in Trello much because the labels vary from Board to Board.

I had this in Chrome but it got removed and I can't find the addon or remember what it's name was.

I want a way to configure ONE set of tags available to all cards.

Use Case for tags

- `#today`  - so I can see what's on my plate TODAY
- `#week`   - you get the idea

Comment: Please don't ask us to help you find the thing that you lost that does what you want. Just ask how to do what it is that you want to do. Else, this will get closed as a "recommendation question".

Answer (score 1):

If the labels aren't working for you, just simply putting that tag text in the description should work.

The search function for Trello searches *all* the cards, not just the ones on the current board.